# get radio value using jquery using .prop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I want a form where the user has 3 different radio buttons and once one is clicked a different message will display depending on which radio button they pick.

Here is some of my code:

```js
 if ($('#Jordanstown').prop('checked')) 
  {
   alert("Yeah, we are on the same campus")
   }
   
   if ($('#Belfast').prop('checked')) {
   alert("Ah, we are not on the same site")
   }
```

```html
<form name ="mycampous">

<input type ="radio" name ="Jordanstown">Jordanstwon</input>
<input type ="radio" name ="Belfast">Belfast</input>
<input type = "button" value="select" onclick= "campous();"> </input>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the runnable snippets. What you want is not an "if", but an event. Look into jQuery event binding.

Comment: no i'm nearly sure that it's if I should be doing

Comment: You want to display the alert message on selecting one of the radio buttons or after selecting a radio and then clicking submit ??

Comment: With different names, radio buttons don't form a radio group. This is bad UI design. You should be using checkboxes.

Comment: Don't think you should have same names for radio buttons ? Because at any time, you want only one of them to be selected, is that your intent ?

Comment: Keep distracting non-essentials out of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll change your HTML little bit to add a class to all radio buttons so that I don't have to use the `input[type='radio']` selector which is slow.

Also radio buttons should have same `name`, if you want only one of them to be selected at any given time, so you need to mention some `value` to differentiate between two radio buttons like below

```
<form name ="mycampous">

 <input class="radio" type ="radio" name="city" value ="Jordanstown">Jordanstwon</input>
 <input class="radio" type ="radio" name="city" value ="Belfast">Belfast</input>
 <input type = "button" value="select" onclick= "campous();"> </input>

</form>
```

And then in your script, look for the `change` event on these radio buttons

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.radio').on('change', function(e){
    var radioValue = $(this).val();
    if(radioValue === 'Jordanstown'){
      alert("Yeah, we are on the same campus");
    } else if(radioValue === 'Belfast'){
      alert("Ah, we are not on the same site");
    }
  });

});
```

Here's a [bin](http://jsbin.com/qeqosuzexo/1/edit?html,js,output) to play with :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type ="radio" name ="Jordanstown"  id="Jordanstown">Jordanstwon</input>
 <input type ="radio" name ="Belfast"  id="Belfast">Belfast</input>
 <input type = "button" value="select" onclick= "campous();"> </input>
</form>
```

I added the `id` attributes since `$('#Belfast')` is selector for the ID not NAME.

I take it that you have the javascript sample wrapped in click event, something like this:

```
$('form').on('click', ':radio', function(){

  if ($('#Jordanstown').prop('checked')) 
   {
     alert("Yeah, we are on the same campus");
   }

   if ($('#Belfast').prop('checked')) {
    alert("Ah, we are not on the same site");
   }
});
```

Preferably, you should also have given the form an id to narrow down the DOM search.

**EDIT**

I just re-read your question. You're trying to alert the **clicked** radio. It should be:

```
$('form#ID_OF_FORM').on('click', ':radio', function(){

   if( $(this).is('#Jordanstown') ){
       alert("Yeah, we are on the same campus");
   }else{
       alert("Ah, we are not on the same site");
   }


});
```

Provided your form's ID is ID_OF_FORM.

Comment: Do you have any error message? Have you used a browser console to check? Perhaps some syntax error? Are your other javascript codes on the same page running well?

Comment: yes I have and can see a number of errors but no idea what they mean

Comment: Start by copying them (all) , then paste as EDIT under your question. Right now, I'm off to work though!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
    function campous(){
        var value = $("[name='mycampous']").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
<form name="mycampous">
    <input name="campus" type="radio" value="Jordanstown">Jordanstwon</input>
    <input name="campus" type="radio" value="Belfast">Belfast</input>
    <input type="button" value="select" onclick="campous();"> </input>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7Lj1bL6/

Comment: close but still not what I want